# What controls value of "Identifier" in update site properties?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tycho

When viewing details of a feature update site I want to install I see what looks like a custom name for "Identifier" property, as seen below.

[image]

For my feature update site I see what seems to be a generated identifier, something like R20140804.com.my.plugin (in my case it looks like suffix is ID set in category.xml). How can I control what the value of identifier property is, thus omitting qualifier value?

I am using Tycho to build my product and other features, so perhaps it's setting in Tycho build?

Comment: Are you defining a category for the feature? I think it may come from that.

Comment: @greg-449 I have a feature that defines category. That category includes other features in it. I defined ID for the category, other than that I don't see where else I can add property to define Identifier.

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you are actually looking for. Could you post the relevant parts of the feature.xml and/or category.xml?

Comment: @oberlies Here is my category.xml that is building update site - http://pastebin.mozilla.org/5993143. When I view properties for the already built update site I see this http://i.imgur.com/FKTxJGZ.png. As you can see identifier is R20140815-1437.iWayCoreServices. Obviously iWayCoreServices suffix comes from category.xml, but where does timestamp R20140815-1437 comes from and how can I remove it from identifier value?

Comment: Now I understand your question - but relevant information should not be hidden in comments. Please edit your question so that it contains all relevant information.